# HTML form is not submitting correctly

Tags: php, html

I'm still new on coding and currently I'm doing some experiments with HTML and PHP.

A contact form was created with HTML, and I'm having an issue when pressing the submit button nothing is appearing on the screen. I would like to get the data entered for now and eventually later on I would like to send an email. HTML and PHP code could be found hereunder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>kurtattard.org</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="logo"></div>

            <nav class="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Event</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <h1>Contact Us</h1>
        </header>

        <form>

        <div class ="textform">
            <form method="post" action="/contact.php">

                <label>Name</Label>
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Insert your Name and Surname">

                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Insert your email address">

                <label>Message</label>
                <input type="message-box" name="message" placeholder="Enter your message">

                <input type="submit" name="submit">

                <!--<button type="submit" name="submit">Send Mail</button>-->

            </form>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

The PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ //someone submitted the form 
    if(isset($_POST['name'])){ //they entered a name or something 
        echo 'hello from '; 
        echo htmlentities(trim($_POST['name']),ENT_NOQUOTES); 
    }else{ //or they did not 
        echo 'type a name'; 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Forgot to add my php code<?php



if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
//someone submitted the form
    if(isset($_POST['name'])){
         //they entered a name or something
         echo 'hello from ';
         echo htmlentities(trim($_POST['name']),ENT_NOQUOTES);
    }else{
         //or they did not
         echo 'type a name';
    }
} 



?>

Comment: Just edit your post

Comment: Please edit your post to include the PHP https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50745125/edit.

Comment: Try and make the title reflect the issue your having, it's a bit too generic ATM.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you have small typo in your code. You have added extra open `<form>` tag. Remove it and your code will work like charm.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>kurtattard.org</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="logo"></div>

        <nav class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Event</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <h1>Contact Us</h1>
        </header>

         <!-- <form>  Remove this -->

        <div class ="textform">
            <form method="post" action="contact.php">

                <label>Name</Label>
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Insert your Name and Surname">

                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Insert your email address">

                <label>Message</label>
                <input type="message-box" name="message" placeholder="Enter your message">

                <input type="submit" name="submit">

                <!--<button type="submit" name="submit">Send Mail</button>-->

            </form>
        </div>

        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks All.. now im being redirected to the php link when clicking on submit button